# If a polyhedron's faces and vertex figures are convex, is the polyhedron convex?

Tags: geometry, 3d, convex-geometry, polyhedra, discrete-geometry

Suppose a polyhedron's faces are convex polygons, and its vertex figures are convex spherical polygons (or convex cones, depending on definitions). Must the polyhedron be convex?

As a counter-example for the analogous question in 2D, the pentagram $\{5/2\}$ has convex "faces" (line segments) and convex vertex figures ($36^\circ$ arcs; less than $180^\circ$) but is a non-convex, self-intersecting polygon.

The polyhedron may be in 3D Euclidean, spheric, or hyperbolic space. -- Actually it doesn't matter, because these all have standard embeddings in 4D:

$$\mathbb E^3=\{(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb R^4\mid w=1\}$$
$$\mathbb S^3=\{(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb R^4\mid x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1\}$$
$$\mathbb H^3=\{(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb R^4\mid x^2+y^2+z^2-w^2=-1,\;w>0\}$$

The polyhedron is represented as a cone (or its intersection with the hypersurface). A point in 3D is represented as a ray, all the positive scalar multiples of some vector in $\mathbb R^4$. So we might as well work in $\mathbb S^3$, and use the standard dot product, though the following could be formulated in terms of general linear algebra (e.g. using quotient spaces instead of orthogonal complements).

---

Let $A$ be an [abstract 3-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_polytope), and $A_k$ be the set of rank $k$ elements of $A$, for $k=-1,0,1,2,3$.

Let $\sigma$ be a function on $A$ with the following properties:

- If $x\in A_k$, then $\sigma x$ is a $(k+1)$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb R^4$. (If you prefer, consider its intersection with $\mathbb S^3$, which is then a $k$-dimensional geodesic subspace.)
- If $x\leq y$ in $A$, then $\sigma x\subseteq\sigma y$.

This function is a *realization* of $A$. (It's *nondegenerate* if the last part is strengthened: $x\leq y$ if and only if $\sigma x\subseteq\sigma y$.)

Let $v$ be a function on incident pairs in $A$ (differing in rank by $1$) with the following properties:

- If $A_k\ni x<y\in A_{k+1}$, then $v(x,y)\in\mathbb S^3$ is a unit vector orthogonal to $\sigma x$ and contained in $\sigma y$. Since the dimensions differ by $1$, there are only $2$ such unit vectors, differing in sign. (This vector $v(x,y)$ is supposed to point from $\sigma x$ to the "inside" of $\sigma y$, and $-v(x,y)$ to the "outside". These notions make sense for convex polytopes, and less sense for self-intersecting polytopes.)
- If $A_{k-1}\ni w<x<z$ and $x\neq y$ and $w<y<z\in A_{k+1}$, then the exterior product $v(w,x)\wedge v(x,z)=-v(w,y)\wedge v(y,z)$. (Note that $v(w,x)\cdot v(x,z)=0$ by the previous property.) Both of these unit bivectors are contained in the $1$-dimensional space $\bigwedge^2\big(\sigma w^\perp\cap\sigma z\big)$, so they must be equal up to sign. We require opposite signs. (If going from vertex $w$ to edge $x$ to face $z$ is turning clockwise, then going from vertex $w$ to the other edge $y$ to face $z$ should be turning anticlockwise.)

This function gives a kind of orientation of the polyhedron. It also gives the angles in faces, and the dihedral angles. Suppose $w<x<z$ and $w<y<z$ are two edges meeting at a vertex in a face; then the angle $\theta$ between the edges is completely determined (modulo $2\pi$) by $\cos\theta=v(w,x)\cdot v(w,y)$ and $\sin\theta=v(w,x)\cdot v(y,z)$.

In fact, given $A$, and the angles and edge lengths, we can reconstruct $\sigma$ and $v$, up to isometry of $\mathbb S^3$. Likewise, given $A$ and $v$, we can reconstruct $\sigma$.

All of that is just my idea of an (oriented) not-necessarily-convex polyhedron in spheric space. (Of course it could be modified for Euclidean or hyperbolic space. But those modifications only involve the metrical properties, not the incidence relations or convexity.)

---

Now to formalize the question. I'll use the notation $[x,z]_k=\{y\in A_k\mid x\leq y\leq z\}$.

Edges are convex:

$$\forall w\in A_{-1},\;\forall z\in A_1,\;\forall x\in[w,z]_0,\;\forall y\in[w,z]_0, \\ (y=x)\lor\big(v(x,z)\cdot v(w,y)>0\big).$$

Angles in faces are convex:

$$\forall w\in A_0,\;\forall z\in A_2,\;\forall x\in[w,z]_1,\;\forall y\in[w,z]_1, \\ (y=x)\lor\big(v(x,z)\cdot v(w,y)>0\big).$$

Dihedral angles are convex:

$$\forall w\in A_1,\;\forall z\in A_3,\;\forall x\in[w,z]_2,\;\forall y\in[w,z]_2, \\ (y=x)\lor\big(v(x,z)\cdot v(w,y)>0\big).$$

Faces are convex:

$$\forall w\in A_{-1},\;\forall z\in A_2,\;\forall x\in[w,z]_1,\;\forall y\in[w,z]_0, \\ (y\leq x)\lor\big(v(x,z)\cdot v(w,y)>0\big)$$

(in addition to edge and angle convexity for the face $z$; but we've already specified edge and angle convexity for everything).

Vertex figures are convex:

$$\forall w\in A_0,\;\forall z\in A_3,\;\forall x\in[w,z]_2,\;\forall y\in[w,z]_1, \\ (y\leq x)\lor\big(v(x,z)\cdot v(w,y)>0\big).$$

Polyhedron is convex?

$$\forall w\in A_{-1},\;\forall z\in A_3,\;\forall x\in[w,z]_2,\;\forall y\in[w,z]_0, \\ (y\leq x)\lor\big(v(x,z)\cdot v(w,y)>0\big)$$

---

In words, a polyhedron is *convex*, if each vertex is inside the half-space for each face (unless the vertex is part of the face), and the faces and vertex figures are convex polygons.

I haven't shown that this definition of a convex polyhedron is equivalent to the usual definitions (intersection of a finite set of half-spaces, convex hull of a finite set of points in 3D, or conical hull of a finite set of vectors in 4D). At least, I have shown it to myself. If someone wants to ask a new Question about the equivalence, I suppose I could answer. For now, take it for granted.

---

Here's an idea for a proof, in the case of Euclidean space.

An element $x\in A_k$ is realized as a $k$-dimensional affine subspace $\sigma x\subset\mathbb E^3\cong\mathbb R^3$. Let's ignore the distinction between a $0$-dimensional subspace and the unique point it contains, so that a vertex $x\in A_0$ has $\sigma x\in\mathbb E^3$ rather than $\sigma x\subset\mathbb E^3$.

Let $l\in A_{-1}$ and $g\in A_3$ be the least and greatest elements. Take an arbitrary face $f$ of the polyhedron, with inward normal vector $v(f,g)$. Let $c\in\mathbb R$ be the constant such that $v(f,g)\cdot\sigma x=c$ for all vertices $x\leq f$. We want to show that $v(f,g)\cdot\sigma x>c$ for all other vertices $x\not\leq f$.

Certainly $v(f,g)\cdot\sigma y>c$ for any vertex $y$ adjacent to a vertex $x\leq f$. Since the vertex figures are convex, we have $v(f,g)\cdot v(x,e)>0$ for any edge $x\leq e\not\leq f$. The adjacent vertex is $\sigma y=\sigma x+t\,v(x,e)$, where $t>0$ is the length of the edge; thus $v(f,g)\cdot\sigma y=v(f,g)\cdot\sigma x+t\,v(f,g)\cdot v(x,e)>c$. By similar reasoning, given $x\leq f$, any vertex $y$ in a face containing $x$ also has $v(f,g)\cdot\sigma y>c$, because $\sigma y$ is in the (2D) convex cone generated by two edges $e,e'\geq x$.

So we have, at least, a subset $B\subseteq A$ of the polyhedron, where all vertices are known to be either in $f$ or on the positive side of $f$. Consider $B$ as a surface, with a curve as its boundary. Take the vertex $x$ on the boundary of $B$ with the smallest value of $v(f,g)\cdot\sigma x$. It follows that $v(f,g)\cdot v(x,e)\geq0$ for any edge $e\geq x$ on the boundary, as that edge connects $x$ to another vertex on the boundary which must not have a smaller dot product with $v(f,g)$. Add to $B$ the faces incident with $x$, along with their edges and vertices, thus changing the boundary of $B$ so that it no longer contains $x$. It should be the case that any such new vertex $y$ has $v(f,g)\cdot\sigma y\geq v(f,g)\cdot\sigma x$, as a result of the convexity of the vertex figure at $x$ (but I'm not sure about this). Repeat until $B=A$. (Since the polyhedron is connected, every vertex will be reached.) The dot product with $v(f,g)$ is always increasing, thus always greater than $c$.

Can we fill in the gaps in this proof? Can it be modified for spheric space?

---

The argument in the previous section depends on finiteness, to find a minimum, and to reach all vertices eventually. I haven't yet specified that $A$ must be a finite set.

Here's an infinite counter-example: a pentagrammic cylinder, or a stack of pentagrammic prisms, in hyperbolic space.

Using hyperbolic cylindrical coordinates, the vertices are located at

$$x_{(m,n)}=(\sinh(a)\cos(2m\cdot72^\circ),\sinh(a)\sin(2m\cdot72^\circ),\cosh(a)\sinh(nb),\cosh(a)\cosh(nb)),$$
$$m\in\mathbb Z\bmod5,\quad n\in\mathbb Z.$$

($a$ is the cylinder's radius. $b$ is a translation distance along the cylinder's axis.)

The polyhedron's faces are "rectangles", with vertex sets of the form $\{x_{(m,n)},x_{(m,n+1)},x_{(m+1,n)},x_{(m+1,n+1)}\}$. These are convex. (The angles in a face are less than $90^\circ$, because of the hyperbolic geometry. We need a word to replace "rectangle" which refers to symmetry rather than angles.)

The polyhedron's vertex figures are also convex, being rhombic. (In Euclidean space, one type of edge would have a dihedral angle of $180^\circ$, violating strict convexity, but in hyperbolic space it's less than $180^\circ$.)

The polyhedron as a whole is not convex, because the plane containing $\{x_{(0,0)},x_{(0,1)},x_{(1,0)},x_{(1,1)}\}$ has some vertices on both sides; e.g. $x_{(2,0)}$ and $x_{(3,0)}$ are separated by that plane.

Of course this could be projected to Euclidean space (Beltrami-Klein model; divide the first three coordinates by the fourth), but then it would have less symmetry, and two accumulation points $(0,0,\pm1)$.

Comment: The answer is surely *Yes*. This may be in Ziegler's *Lectures on Polytopes*. If you convert the convex cones to planes, then you should get the polyhedron as an intersection of halfspaces.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke - What makes that work in 3D but not in 2D?

Comment: @mr_e_man: I think I cannot help, as you are seeking to exclude possibilities I myself don't see.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke - I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that it should in fact work in 2D? Again I'll point to [star polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_polygon). Perhaps Ziegler and you consider a polytope as merely a subset of space (rather than some other structure such as a collection of subspaces), thus disallowing self-intersection....

Comment: I haven't fleshed this out, but I think there may be a topological approach here - since the convex cones cause every point's neighborhood to look like a plane (with a canonical orientation to the surface as well), you obtain an oriented 2D manifold, but if you sort of "project out to the sphere at infinity" you obtain a covering of $S^2$, which you can conclude must actually be $S^2$. From there it should be possible to rule out doubly-covered regions of this projection by the convexity of vertex figures, I think, though I haven't sorted out the details.

Comment: (This approach doesn't falsely generalize to "proving" the impossibility of star polygons, because $S^1$ doesn't have trivial fundamental group.)